# jetty server not support @PersistenceContext, how can i do this?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jetty

i tack my project to war file and deploy in jetty server it was shows the following error, but it deploy in weblogic server means it will work fine.

```
 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory. BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'testDataPersistence' is defined
```

XML file is containing

```
<bean id="testEntityManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testDataPersistence" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.samp" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

java code

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testDataPersistence", name = "testEntityManager")
 private void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
     this.em = em;
 }
```

Comment: `No bean named 'testDataPersistence' is defined`. And what did you define? ...

Comment: updated my code @neil stockton